# Is there a way to use custom icons in React Native without any third party library?

Tags: react-native, svg, icons

I know we can't use `SVG` directly in `RN`, but we can convert it to `.ttf`. My question is how can we use those `TTF` files without installing `react-native-vector-icons` and similar libraries? All tutorials I could find on Google involve installing such libraries, but I'm not allowed to use them in my project. I'm not allowed to implement any solution that requires changes in the android or `iOS` folders.

What do I know so far?

Well, I can go to [fontello.com](https://fontello.com/) and convert any `SVG` icon to `.ttf`. It'll generate a folder containing the font file and also a `config.json` file.

What I don't know?

I don't know how to use the files generated by **Fontello** to display the icon without the help of any library.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, you can put the TTF files inside android/app/src/assets/fonts and use them directly as a font family name. The problem is that I'm creating an NPM package, so it's not a suitable solution. So I discovered that `react-native-svg` doesnt'need any special configuration, and you can use the XML code directly by importing `SvgXml` from the library.